# If I run two different classes in IntelliJ, will they share resources (like CPU)?

Tags: performance, intellij-idea, benchmarking

I'm timing some libraries' basic operations for speed. I've written one test class for each candidate library and one method for each operation. If I run all of these test classes at the same time in IntelliJ, will they share resources and *significantly* muddy the results?

The reason I ask is that one of the libraries has been running for hours and I'm wondering if I can safely begin testing another while it is still working.

Comment: Anything that you do on your machine during a benchmark will influence the benchmark results. If you want accurate results, do not do anything resource demanding at the same time, especially not another benchmark.

Comment: @Zabuzard I guess I should qualify my question with "significantly muddy".

Comment: This has nothing to do with Intellij, its machine-wide. Lets say you are playing a game during your benchmark and that game takes 90% CPU and 50% RAM. Those resources are now in use, they cant be used by the benchmark anymore. So the benchmark will run with 10% CPU only. And worse, if the games CPU usage fluctuates, the benchmark will fluctuate as well, so does its performance and your results are heavily biased by the games CPU usage over time.

Comment: @Zabuzard Okay, if I understand you correctly, the CPU will allot as much as possible to the first test being run, and therefore any follow on tests won't get a fair share of the pie. Thank you.

Comment: CPU scheduling is done by the OS using complex algorithms and heuristics. My point is more that, when your hitting the resource limits (which benchmarks typically do), then every program is sufferring from the fact that they dont have the full resources available anymore and since u cant easily control this and usage fluctuates a lot, the results are worthless.

Comment: If you do not hit limits at all, because your benchmarks maybe only run at max 2% CPU, you will likely not see any impact. Problems start as soon as you exhaust or really stress out any resource (CPU, cores, RAM, network, disk, ...).

Comment: @Zabuzard Okay, but I am running multiple applications during this test and my CPU is at 18% utilization, and memory is 38%. So perhaps I am using the term "benchmarking" a little too loosely? How might I rephrase my question to be understandable in this light?

Comment: Well, you got an answer now. Your results are influenced. But it sounds like the impact is likely not big. But, as usual, _educated guesses_ about performance and benchmarks tend to be quite off. Measure the difference. Do it once isolated, once together, see if you see a noticable difference. I doubt anyone can give you a concrete answer for such a broad question that is so heavily dependend on the exact situation and details.

Comment: @Zabuzard: It's usually not just memory *space* that's important, it's memory *bandwidth*.  On a multi-core CPU, each core has its own L1 and L2 caches, but L3 is shared and so are the memory controllers.  If your code has many L2 cache misses, its performance may depend on shared resources.  That can include L3 cache footprint, and L3 / DRAM bandwidth.  At least on Intel CPUs where you have one large L3; on AMD Zen, each CCX of 4 cores has its own L3 cache, so on a Zen with more than 4 cores, you can have 2 threads not competing for L3 space / bandwidth, only DRAM bandwidth.